# How to locate to a default location on incorrect GET value using headers

Tags: php, header

I am trying to locate my php header to a specific location on receiving a GET value and if the value is incorrect, it will locate to a default location like home.php

here is what I've done so far

```
<?php
// Check which page is queried

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $got = $_GET['page'];
}
else {
    $got = 'home';
}

// Now goto that location

if(header('Location: '.$got.'.php')){
    header('Location: '.$got.'.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: home.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Besides, you really should whitelist `$got` against valid params (at least with a regular expression), it's a big security hole - one is able to navigating to every file he wants just by using your `$_GET['page']` parameter. A possible attacker might be able to relocate someone to a different server.

Comment: great community 6 answers in just 6 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists)() function.

You would do something like this;

```
$got = 'home';
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
  if(file_exists($_GET['page'].".php"))
  {
    $got = $_GET['page'];
  }

}

header('Location: '.$got.'.php');
exit;
```

**Edit**
You would be better of by whitelisting the pages you would allow the users to see:

```
$got = 'home';
$whitelist = array('contact', 'about', 'blog', ...); // could come from your database
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
  if(file_exists($_GET['page'].".php") && in_array($_GET['page'], $whitelist))
  {
    $got = $_GET['page'];
  }

}

header('Location: '.$got.'.php');
exit;
```

This ensures that only the views you allow can be accessed.

Comment: +1 second approach is the way to go and provides the security too.

Comment: I have just checked it. I'm very late but its not working. I have checked by sending ?page=contact (while contact.php is there) but its still opening home.php !

Comment: @Yousuf check the whitelist, make the if condition checks out, do some debugging.

Comment: @Repox I think in in_array first argument should be needle and second should be haystack ? Haven't you reversed them ?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (file_exists( $got . '.php') {
  header('Location: '.$got.'.php');  
} else {
  header('Location: home.php');
}
```

But better create a whitelist of available pages, because such code would be vulnerable to header injections

Comment: Use `exit()` after `header` :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file exists

```
if (file_exists($got . ".php") 
{
    header('Location: ...');
    exit;
}
else
{
    header('Location: ...');
    exit;
}
```

Obviously you need to make sure there have been no previous headers sent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to use [file_exists](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it searches for all your php pages in a directory that you whitelist (dynamically) then compares it to the get request to see if that page is in your pages directory. if it is then it loads it else it loads your home.php

```
$page = array();
$it = DirectoryIterator($dir);

foreach ($it as $page) {
    $pages[] = $page;
}

if (isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)
    header("Location: " . $pages[$_GET] . ".php"); // or require_once $page . '.php';
else
    header("Location: home.php"); // or require_once "home.php";
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to check whether the request returns HTTP 200

```
$http = curl_init($url);
// do your curl thing here
$result = curl_exec($http);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($http_status != 200)
{
    $url = "/home.php";
}
header('Location: '.$url);
```