# Unable to understand in_array()

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
$whitelist = array('contact', 'about', 'user');
$_GET['page'] = array('contact');
$test = $_GET['page'];
if(isset($test))
{
  if(in_array($whitelist, $test))
  {
    $got = $test;
    echo $got;
  }
  else 
  {
    $got = 'home';
    echo $got;  
  }
}
?>
```

Now here, I should get the result as 'contact' but I'm getting 'home'. Why is that ?

Comment: It looks like your trying to find an array in an array, try changing it to $test = "contact"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in_array first argument should be needle (meaning: what you are looking for) and second should be haystack (meaning: where we are looking for).

I think that you reversed those, as well as needl should be string (or other variable type), but not array.

So your script should look like this:

```
<?php
$whitelist = array('contact', 'about', 'user');
$test = 'contact';
if(isset($test))
{
  if(in_array($test, $whitelist))
  {
    $got = $test;
    echo $got;
  }
  else 
  {
    $got = 'home';
    echo $got;  
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check the following link what Repox answered my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978798/how-to-locate-to-a-default-location-on-incorrect-get-value-using-headers

Answer (score 3):

Because whitelist is an array of strings and $_GET['page'] is an array, not a string. And you've got the paramters the wrong way round.

Comment: Check the following link what Repox answered my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978798/how-to-locate-to-a-default-location-on-incorrect-get-value-using-headers

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$whitelist = array('contact', 'about', 'user');
$_GET['page'] = 'contact';
$test = $_GET['page'];
if(isset($test))
{
  if(in_array($test, $whitelist))
  {
    $got = $test;
    echo $got;
  }
  else 
  {
    $got = 'home';
    echo $got;  
  }
}
?>
```